# Counts for time range per day

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table something like this

```
create table widgets
(
   id primary key,
   created_at timestamp,
   -- other fields
)
```

Now I want a query that shows the count of widgets with `created_at` between multiple time ranges for each day. For example, the count of widgets with `created_at` between 00:00:00 and 11:59:59 and the count between 12:00:00 and 23:59:59. The output would look something like this:

```
date           | morning widgets (before noon) | evening widgets (after noon) |
---------------|-------------------------------|------------------------------|
2022-05-01     |            ##                 |           ##                 |
2022-05-02     |            ##                 |           ##                 |
2022-05-03     |            ##                 |           ##                 |
2022-05-04     |            ##                 |           ##                 |
... etc.
```

So far, I figured out I can get counts per day:

```
select created_at::date as created_at_date, count(*) as total
from widgets
where created_at::date >= '2022-05-01' -- where clause for illustration purposes only and not critical to the central question here
group by created_at::date
```

I'm learning about windowing functions, specifically `partition by`. I think this will help me get what I want, but not sure. How do I do this?

I'd prefer a "standard SQL" solution. If necessary, I'm on postgres and can use anything specific to its flavor of SQL.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih postgres

Comment: Could you provide some text sample data and expect the result? that really help

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks for looking at this. The desired output is shown as a table in my question where "##" should be the number of rows with the given date and between the described time period. I added an initial attempt at a query, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we can try to use the condition window function to make it.

- `morning widgets (before noon)` : between 00:00:00 and 11:59:59
- `evening widgets (after noon)` : between 12:00:00 and 23:59:59

put the condition in aggregate function by `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT created_at::date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN created_at >= created_at::date AND created_at <=  created_at::date + INTERVAL '12 HOUR' THEN 1 END) ,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN created_at >= created_at::date + INTERVAL '12 HOUR' AND  created_at <= created_at::date+ INTERVAL '1 DAY' THEN 1 END)
FROM  widgets w
GROUP BY created_at::date
ORDER BY created_at::date
```

[sqliddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3495ca3a67083f6c5ea0b69327f9af6)

Comment: Thanks. That exactly answers the question as I stated it here. How would I generalize the interval calculation to be between any two arbitrary times of day?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What do you mean `two arbitrary times of day?` could you give us a sample?

Comment: I think I figured it out: `COUNT(CASE WHEN created_at::time between '00:00:00' and '11:59:59' THEN 1 END)`. Now I can change the start and end times to whatever I want.